# CS50 problem result is not right and I don't understand why

Tags: c, string, loops, computer-science, cs50

I'm really sorry to bother but I have a problem and I don't know how to fix it. I've been doing CS5O and in Problem Set 2 I've been receiving wrong results and I don´t understand what I did wrong. It should be giving me "Before Grade 1" for the sentence "One fish. Two fish. Red fish. Blue fish." but is giving me Grade 2, it is giving Grade 14 for a sentence that is Grade 16+. Can someone help me? This is my code:

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <math.h>

int count_letters(string text);
int count_word(string text);
int count_sentences(string text);

int letters;
int words;
int sentences;

int main(void)
{

    string text = get_string("Text: ");

    printf("Text: %s\n", text);
    count_letters(text);
    count_word(text);
    count_sentences(text);

    float L = 100 * (letters / words);
    float S = 100 * (sentences / words);

    int index = round(0.0588 * L - 0.296 * S - 15.8);

    if (index < 1)
    {
        printf("Before Grade 1\n");
    } else if (index > 16)
    {
        printf("Grade 16+\n");
    } else
    {
        printf("Grade: %i\n", index);
    }
}
int count_letters(string text)
{
    letters = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(text); i++)
    {
        if ((text[i] >= 65 && text[i] <= 99) || (text[i] >= 97 && text[i] <= 122))
        {
            letters++;
        }
    }
    return letters;}
int count_word(string text)
{
    words = 1;

    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(text); i++)
    {
        if (isspace(text[i]))
        {
            words++;
        }
    }
    return words;}
int count_sentences(string text)
{
    sentences = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(text); i++)
    {
        if (text[i] == 33 || text[i] == 46 || text[i] == 63)
        {
            sentences++;
        }
    }
    return sentences;
}
```

Thank you!!

Comment: Do you realise that `100 * (letters / words)` is performing integer division? I suggest `100.0 * letters / words`

Comment: `(text[i] >= 65` You should not use magic numbers. If you mean the character `'A'`, use the characer `'A'` instead of some number that does not mean anything to the reader and is only true if your implementation uses ASCII character set.

Comment: Typo: `text[i] <= 99` should be `text[i] <= 90` but don't even do that: use `text[i] <= 'Z'`. and even better would be `isalpha(text[i])`

Comment: The code 'captures' the return value from the function `get_string()`. Why are global variables being used? Why not local variables inside `main()` that capture the return values from the 3 different tallying functions? Global variables are a bad habit that should not be started...

Answer (score 0):

Regarding types:

There's a phenomenon sometimes called "sloppy typing" which basically means carelessly spamming out any random variable type in the code and then wonder why nothing works. Here's some things you need to know:

- Integer division truncates the result by dropping the remainder. `int` is an integer, constants such as `100` is also `int`. Thus `3/2` evaluates to `1` in C.
- Unless you have very good and exotic reasons<sup>1)</sup>, you should pretty much never use the type `float` in a C program.

  On high end systmes like PC, always use `double`. All the default math functions use `double`, for example `round()`. If you wish to use them with `float` you'd use a special function `roundf()`. Similarly, all floating point constants `1.0` are of type `double`. If you want them to be float you'd use `1.0f`.
- For the two above reasons, make it a habit of never mixing different types in the same expression. Do not mix integer and floating point. Do not mix `float` and `double`. Mixing types can lead to unexpected implicit conversion problems, accidental truncation, loss of precision and so on.

So for example a line such as `float L = 100 * (letters / words);` needs to be rewritten to explicitly use `double` everywhere:

```
double L = 100.0 * ((double)letters / (double)words);
```

<sup>1) Like using a microcontroller with single precision floating point FPU but only software floating point `double`. Or a FPU where `double` would be far less efficient.</sup>

---

Regarding functions and global variables:

The variables `letters`, `words` and `sentences` could have been declared locally inside main(), since your functions return the values to use anyway.

Declaring global variables like you do is considered very bad practice for multiple reasons. It exposes variables to other parts of the program that shouldn't have access, which in turn increases chances of accidental/intentional abuse since the variables are available everywhere. It increases the chances for naming collisions. It is unsafe in multi-threaded applications. It's universally bad; don't do this.

Instead pass variables to/from functions by parameters and return values.

---

Regarding "magic numbers":

Dropping a constant such as `0.0588` in the middle of source code, with zero explanation where that number comes from or what it does, is known as "magic numbers". This is bad practice since the reader of the code has no clue what it's therefore. The reader is most often yourself, one year from now, when you have forgotten all about what the code does, so it's a form of self-torture.

So instead of typing out some number like that, use a `#define` or `const` variable with a meaningful name, then use that meaningful name in the equation/expression instead.

In case of symbol table values, we don't have to invent that meaningful name ourselves, since C already has a built-in mechanism for it. Instead of `text[i] >= 65` you should type `text[i] >= 'A'`, which is 100% equivalent but much more readable.

An advanced detail regarding symbol table values is that they aren't actually guaranteed to be adjacant. Something like `ch >= 'A' && ch <= 'Z'` may work on classic 7 bit ASCII, but it's non-portable and also don't conver "locale" - local language-specific letters (as seen in Spanish, French, German and so on - almost every major language using latin letters). The portable solution to this is to use `isupper` or `islower` from ctype.h. Or in your case better yet, `isalpha`.

---

Regarding code formatting:

Don't invent some own non-standard formatting. There are some things regarding code formatting that are subjective, but these are not:

- Always use empty lines between function bodies.
- Always place the last `}` of a function at a line of its own.